# Starting point to develop Metro UI style application for Printers in Windows 8?

Tags: printing, windows-8, system.printing

Currently we have an application which allows the user to include/remove the pages, images and text(which is given to the printer, using hooking we are getting the printed document and then processing it).

Now we want to develop the same for Metro UI style application for Windows 8.

So what is the starting point to develop the above said application using XAML and C#?

Should we need to learn HTML5, Javascript to develop Metro UI style application?

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with Javascript and HTML, then using Javascript could be what you want. Microsoft claims that Javascript, C++ and C# are just different projections of WinRT APIs. So theoretically, if you can write the app in C#+XMAL, then you should also be able to write it in Javascript+HTML5.

So the question is really which language you are more proficient in or which language do you prefer to use.

Visual Studio 11 Express Beta and Windows 8 Consumer Previews are available for free at this point, so there is no cost for you to start your development.

Here is a bundle of Consumer Preview samples:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-8-Modern-Style-App-Samples

Here is a link for the printing API:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448418(v=vs.85).aspx

Hope this will get you started on your application.